# Can't insert a new line and tab with sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed, tabs, newline

I can't insert a new line and tabs with sed

```
 cat /etc/login.conf | sed -e 's|:umask=022:|:umask=022:\\\n:charset=UTF-8:|g'

        :umask=022:\\\n\t\t:charset=UTF-8:\\\n\t\t:lang=en_US.UTF-8:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some sed versions don't support `\n` insertion, you can try with literal `$'\n'` and `$'\t'` character :

```
cat /etc/login.conf | sed -e 's|:umask=022:|:umask=022:\'$'\n\t\t:charset=UTF-8:|g'
```

Comment: No luck, "Illegal variable name"

Comment: Great ! You may accept the answer if you found it useful.